# Найти слово в файле, который лежит в определённой директории

Tags: php, файлы

Есть код

```
<?php

function search_file($dir, $word){
    $result = array();
    $arr=scandir($dir);

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
        $filename = $dir . '/' . $arr[$i];
        if(is_file($filename)){
            $x = file_get_contents($filename);

            $pos=strpos($x, $word);
            if($pos!==false){
                $result[]=$arr[$i];
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
print_r(search_file("test1", "red"));

?>
```

Где здесь ошибка? Скрипт не ищет слово **red**, хотя это слово есть в одном из файлов директории test1

Comment: У меня всё работает. Попробуйте после `$arr=scandir($dir);` написать `print_r($arr)` и посмотрите, что выведется

Comment: слово надо один раз найти?

Comment: попробовал после $arr=scandir($dir); написать print_r($arr); - всё равно ошибки print_r($arr); exit(); - тоже ошибки выдаёт

Answer (score 0, accepted):

print_r(search_file("../../test1", "red"));

Comment: Точно! написал полный путь к директории и сработало!

Answer (score 0):

Вот что у меня получилось
Находит слово, можно дороботать ее, не знаю точно, надо один раз найти слово, или все слова.

```
function find_value($input, $file) {
$handle = @fopen($file, "r");
if ($handle) {
  while (!feof($handle)) {
    $entry_array = explode(":",fgets($handle));
    //print_r($entry_array);
    if ($entry_array[0] == $input) {
      return $entry_array[0];
      }
    }
  fclose($handle);
  }
return NULL;
}


function search_file($dir, $word){
   $result = array();
   $arr=scandir($dir);
        for ($i = 2; $i < count($arr); $i++) { // starting from 2 because we have . and .. directory level

                $filename = $dir . '/' . $arr[$i];
                echo $filename;
              $result[] = find_value($word, $filename);
        }
        return $result;
    }
    var_dump(search_file("test1", "red"));

    ?>
```

Comment: у меня всё равно выдаёт ошибки. Этот файл(в котором пишу код) у меня находится в директории C:\WebServers\home\localhost\www\test1\functions_forms_tasks , а я ищу слова в одном из файлов, которые находятся в директории C:\WebServers\home\localhost\www\test1

Comment: я протестил все работает, какую ошибку он выдает?

Comment: Warning: scandir(test1,test1): Не удается найти указанный файл. (code: 2) in C:\WebServers\home\localhost\www\test1\functions_forms_tasks\iskomoe_slovo.php on line 5 Call Stack: 0.0010 329112 1. {main}() C:\WebServers\home\localhost\www\test1\functions_forms_tasks\iskomoe_slovo.php:0 0.0010 329208 2. search_file() C:\WebServers\home\localhost\www\test1\functions_forms_tasks\iskomoe_slovo.php:20 0.0010 329360 3. scandir()

Comment: C:\WebServers\home\localhost\www\test1\functions_forms_tasks\iskomoe_slovo.php:5 Warning: scandir(test1): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in C:\WebServers\home\localhost\www\test1\functions_forms_tasks\iskomoe_slovo.php on line 5 Call Stack: 0.0010 329112 1. {main}() C:\WebServers\home\localhost\www\test1\functions_forms_tasks\iskomoe_slovo.php:0 0.0010 329208 2. search_file() C:\WebServers\home\localhost\www\test1\functions_forms_tasks\iskomoe_slovo.php:20

Comment: 0.0010 329360 3. scandir() C:\WebServers\home\localhost\www\test1\functions_forms_tasks\iskomoe_slovo.php:5 Warning: scandir(): (errno 2): No such file or directory in C:\WebServers\home\localhost\www\test1\functions_forms_tasks\iskomoe_slovo.php on line 5 Call Stack: 0.0010 329112 1. {main}()

Comment: файл, в котором пишу код назыв. iskomoe_slovo.php

Comment: это я показал ошибки с моего первоначального кода